# Eliminar columnas con todo 0 habiendo texto

Tags: r

Tengo un df

```
df <- read.table(text = '
      X1 X2 X3
1  0  0  0
2  0  0  1
3  0 NA  0
4  0  0  0
5  0  1  1
6  0  0  0
7  0  0  1', header = TRUE)
```

y quiero eliminar todas las columnas cuyos elementos sean todo 0.
Si tiene un NA no la elimina.

```
df %>% select_if (~sum((.)) != 0 | sum(is.na(.x)) > 0) 

X2 X3
  0  0
  0  1
 NA  0
  0  0
  1  1
  0  0
  0  1
```

Pero si tengo una columna con texto

```
df <- read.table(text = '
   X1 X2 X3 X4
1  0  0  0  0
2  0  0  1  1
3  0 NA  0  pepe
4  0  0  0   3
5  0  1  1  4
6  0  0  0  5
7  0  0  1   5', header = TRUE)
```

Da error porque no puede sumar texto.

Habría que comprobar si la columna es numérica y entonces aplicar lo anterior.

Pero no consigo meterle el filtro `is.numeric` a cada columna y que funcione.

El resultado buscado es

```
    X2 X3 X4
    0  0   0
    0  1   1
   NA  0  pepe
    0  0   3
    1  1   4
    0  0   5
    0  1   5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El truco sería convertir primeros las columnas de tipo `character` en un `numeric`:

```
mutate(across(where(is.character), as.numeric))
```

Esto aplica el `as.numeric` en todas las columnas que sean cadenas. Tendrás seguramente un warning, que son los valores como `pepe` que no pueden transformarse en un número, en estos casos el valor final será `NA`.

```
df %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.character), as.numeric)) %>% 
  select_if(~sum((.), na.rm = TRUE) != 0 )

  X2 X3 X4
1  0  0  0
2  0  1  1
3 NA  0 NA
4  0  0  3
5  1  1  4
6  0  0  5
7  0  1  5
Warning message:
Problem while computing `..1 = across(where(is.character), as.numeric)`.
i NAs introduced by coercion
```

Fuente: [dplyr change many data types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27668266/dplyr-change-many-data-types)